# Verb "abound" to ask someone to develop a subject

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, expressions, verbs, spanish

When you're having a conversation, maybe you'd like your counterpart to speak more about what she/he is talking about.

Of course, you could simply say: "could you develop your point?", or something like that; however, in Spanish we have "podrías abundar al respecto?", which roughly translates as "could you abound on it?" or "could you be more abundant in the development of that subject?"

I'm not sure if I can use the verb abound in that way. What would be a good alternative?

Thanks!

==========================================================================

Wow! many great answers! I wish I could select more than one right answer.
I selected "expound" because I never had heard of it; so, it has extra points for increasing my vocabulary. I also like it because it sounds very much like "abound", the one I wanted to use originally.

Thanks to all!

Comment: There is [expound](http://en.wiktionarry.org/wiki/expound)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds a bit like 'abound'. -- You could ask: Could you [expound](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/expound?s=t) on that?

> verb (used without object) to make a detailed statement (often
>   followed by on).

You could also say: Could you [elaborate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/elaborate?s=t)?

> verb (used without object), e·lab·o·rat·ed, e·lab·o·rat·ing. to add
>   details in writing, speaking, etc.; give additional or fuller
>   treatment (usually followed by on or upon): to elaborate upon a theme
>   or an idea.

Comment: I had never heard of "expound". I really liked it! "elaborate" is another great option. Thanks!

Comment: I think *expound* is more to speak in great detail about something in the first place, rather than going into further detail. I like *elaborate* for this more than *expound* +1

Answer (score 4):

I would use [**elucidate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elucidate):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> *transitive verb*
> : to make lucid especially by explanation or analysis
> // *elucidate* a text
>
> *intransitive verb*
> : to give a clarifying explanation

So:

> "Could you *elucidate* [on that subject]"?

---

It has a formal aspect to it, but if you're going to be *informal*, you'd likely just ask, "What do you mean?" or say, "Tell me more."

Comment: Thanks, @Jason Bassford. Elucidate sounds really nice; although, as you said, it is a little bit formal. I didn't know you could use elucidate in that manner.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so.

[Abound](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abound) refers to large quantities of something

You probably want to use [expand on](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expand-on-sth?q=expand%20on):

> Could you *expand on* your point?

Comment: Between *expand on* and *expound*, one, if not both, must be a historical corruption

Comment: Of course! Simple and clear. How did I overlook it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

abundar translates as a phrase, there is no single word:

to go into more depth on a subject
to study a subject in-depth
to go into something further or more in-depth

**abundar and abound are false friends.**

Comment: Thanks. Going in-depth sounds good

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. *Abundant* is used of some *thing* that is in plentiful supply, and *abound*, similarly, refers to there being plenty of something rather than information being detailed. You could perhaps say "Can you enlarge on that topic, please?"

Comment: Karl is asking about "abound,"  not "abundant." Could you edit your answer?

Comment: Thanks, @Kate Bunting. I didn't know you could use "enlarge" in that way. It sounds a little bit funny to me :)

Comment: Try looking up 'enlarge upon'.